# finding the equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A cell phone plan has a basic charge of \$35 a month. The plan includes 400 free minutes and charges 10 cents for each additional minute of usage. Write the monthly cost $C$ as a function of the number $x$ of minutes used and graph $C$ as a function of $x$ for $0 \leq x \leq 600$. 
My answer is $C= 3.5 + .10x$, and the graph will be some thing like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%2035%2b0.10x)
is it right?

Comment: Hmm, say you have talked only for 200 minutes. What would be your monthly cost? Now, look at your graph and see if your answer is right.

Comment: @LordSoth It must be a piecewise function?

Comment: Yes, you should only pay $35$ dollars until $400$ minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember you have $400$ free minutes, so that your equation must reflect that.  I would write

$$C = \begin{cases} 35 & 0 \le x \le 400 \\35 + 0.1 (x-400) & x \gt 400\end{cases}$$

See if you can graph that.

Comment: Oh I see... Thank you